# How to link a static library file in Linux machine

Tags: c++, linux

I have generated a static library for linux x86. How can I statically link this library in Linux?

Comment: One more "can able" and I delete my account.

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
gcc path_to_my_static_lib.a code.c
```

Comment: Or maybe in the reverse order (assuming that `code.c` depends on `static_lib.a` and not the other way around), else you'll get linker errors.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful
http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html

Just start with the basic and read thru the page you will get an idea.